# Redirect to a different apache server for a Domain but keep URL the same

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, reverse-proxy, ports

Hopefully this is easy to do - I just can't figure it out!

I apologise in advance if I get any of the terminology wrong is the question.  My knowledge of web servers is not brilliant!

I have two apache servers within one domain.  One is listening on port 80 (we can call it Apache1)  and the other on port 10080 (Apache2).

What I want to achieve is that when a user enters a certain domain address in the URL bar in the browser (say www.domain.com) , they get redirected from the default server on port 80 to the server listening on port 10088.

I have achieved this using the Redirect keyword in the Apache httpd.conf file of the Apache 1 server like this:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
Redirect / http://www.domain.com:10088/exampleApp
</VirtualHost>
```

While this works, unfortunately it changes the URL in the browser to www.domain.com:10088/exampleApp where I need it to appear to the user with the same domain they entered - www.domain.com

I have tried messing around with ProxyPass and ReverseProxyPass but I could get this to work.  I don't know if a solution can be achieved using URL rewriting or not.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a reverse proxy for this:

If both of your sites are listening on the same server, you can probably just proxy on localhost (127.0.0.1). If not, make sure the domain name can be resolved from Apache1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:10088/exampleApp/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:10088/exampleApp/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I will give this a try tomorrow.  I have no access to the servers from home at the moment.  Could you explain to me the purpose of the ProxyPreserveHost line and why I need it?

Comment: It ensures the host header remains set. If your second Apache server is doing virtual hosting you will probably need this. If there is only one site on second Apache you may not. Probably safer to set it if you're not sure.

Comment: I faced a lot of issues with `ProxyPreserveHost On`. I was facing the issue mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304146/reverse-proxy-from-apache-to-iis-always-fails-with-a-404). Just leaving it as a comment for others. It worked with `ProxyPreserveHost Off`