# Reverse proxy from apache to IIS always fails with a 404

Tags: apache, iis, proxy, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy from apache to an IIS 7 server.

I've setup pretty basic proxy rules.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName MY_APPACHE_SERVER_NAME
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/...
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/...
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://MY_IIS_SERVER_NAME/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://MY_IIS_SERVER_NAME/
</VirtualHost>
```

If I hit the home page through my proxy, I get a 404 error.

On the IIS server side, in the C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr.log file I can see the incoming call and the response set to 404

```
2015-03-27 15:07:36 184.73.82.33 42313 10.79.154.81 443 HTTP/1.1 GET / 404 - NotFound -
2015-03-27 15:07:52 184.73.82.33 42314 10.79.154.81 443 HTTP/1.1 GET / 404 - NotFound -
```

And on the http response I can see that the response comes from the IIS server Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

```
        HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
        Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 15:07:52 GMT
        Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
        Content-Length: 315
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I can't understand why I can't get my home page when hitting the proxy server. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would be interested to find out whether you had more issues with reverse proxy & Apache to IIS. We are considering moving our reverse proxy responsibility to a Windows VM & IIS as we getting some odd Gateway errors etc.

Comment: I haven't had any problem since switching my proxy to apache, everything still works great.

Answer (score 12):

Found my problem, it was the "ProxyPreserveHost On" line. It should have been set to OFF.

The IIS server was answering only to MY_IIS_SERVER_NAME. Since I was calling MY_APPACHE_SERVER_NAME, that name was forwarded to the IIS server and the server didn't recognize that name. hence the 404 error.

My final apache config looked like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName MY_APPACHE_SERVER_NAME
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/...
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/...

    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / https://MY_IIS_SERVER_NAME/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://MY_IIS_SERVER_NAME/
</VirtualHost>
```